# Check if variable is defined with Numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

Sometimes I have a situation where I want to test whether a variable is `0` or `None` or not. In pure Python, this is simply

```
foo == True
```

but when `foo` is possibly a Numpy object (such as `numpy.ndarray`), this does not work anymore and I get the error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. 
 Use a.any() or a.all()
```

and in this case I want `a.any()`, however this fails on non-iterable objects.

Of course I can explicitly check if `foo` is `0` or `None`, but I am wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this.

How can I check if an arbitrary object (both iterable and not) is `True` or not?

Comment: More Pythonically, it's `if foo` - and that'll work with most things. Unfortunately, you'll have to special case `numpy.ndarray` or any other type that's more complex than 0, None, False, len() == 0 equates to False.

Comment: I usually check numpy object to be None with `array is None`, but this doesn't check for zero though. See here for a similar question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086178/python-how-to-check-if-array-is-not-empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`np.all`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) or [`np.any`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) instead of the `.all` method. `np.all` will create an array if it is not one yet.

Comment: Just be aware that this doesn't work as you might think for all iterables: `np.any(False for _ in range(10))` yields `True`. (Of course, it would work if this were a list comprehension instead of a generator.) Basically, it evaluates the logical truth of the iterable instance instead of making an array from the contents.  You can work around this with `np.fromiter`, but it's an extra step.  Still, using `np.all`, etc, is by far the cleanest solution if you just want to deal with most cases.

Comment: This seems like a suitable solution, thanks! The generator exception is not really an issue for me, but it's good to know there are potential pitfalls.

Answer (score 1):

The recipe I use is to surround the statement assuming the existence of a variable in a try except block:

```
try:
    do_something(foo)
except NameError:
    foo = something
```